# Multiple navigation using multiple Fragments hosted by one Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

The idea of using **MVVM** is that view observes `ViewModel`changes and acts. I'm using an `Activity` which uses 7 Fragments and the navigation between them goes through observing individual changes in the Activity from different Fragments and launching/replacing Fragments accordingly. For instance,Fragment `L`  calls `setValue`, then as a result the main Activity receives the event and switches to Fragment M and Fragment M calls `getValue` from the observed `MutableLiveData` and not directly functioning as a listener to changes. Does that the right structure or should each Fragment observe changes by himself ? What would the right way to handle multiple navigations between multiple Fragments

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in what you just said. Fragments should be independent from each other unless they are nested.

If you need communication between fragments that can be done in many ways. The most basic way is to do that through activity. Activity knows how its fragments interact with each other, but fragments remain independent. They can listen to events, no problem here, but make sure you have a 'rule' in your project about how you handle events.

E.g. I prefer having one listener at a time to have the order more predictable. If I want multiple fragments to handle the event, I usually place the handler in the activity and then pass the event to fragments in the exact order I need. Otherwise it might quickly get out of control.

There are other ways too, such as `EventBus`, `BroadcastReceivers` or any other event-based mechanism.

I hope that helps. If I didn't answer your question then to answer it more precisely I'd need the question to be more specific.